# Utilizing ndgrid/meshgrid functionality in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to find functionality in Julia similar to MATLAB's `meshgrid` or `ndgrid`. I know Julia has defined `ndgrid` in [the examples](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/examples/ndgrid.jl) but when I try to use it I get the following error.

> UndefVarError: ndgrid not defined

Anyone know either how to get the builtin `ndgrid` function to work or possibly another function I haven't found or library that provides these methods (the builtin function would be preferred)? I'd rather not write my own in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is actually incomplete - much like asking "how would you translate the English word 'of' into German". The case is that in most code in matlab where ndgrid is ideomatic, the Julia code would rely on dot-broadcasting. Try expanding the question to describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: [VectorizedRoutines.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/VectorizedRoutines.jl) has `meshgrid` and `ndgrid` functions. However, I think that the proper way to do this would be by the creation of a lazy operator as output. Never got to it though.

Comment: How are the function definitions in the linked file run? using `include("$JULIA_HOME/../examples/ndgrid.jl")` or some such statement?

Comment: I've updated the wording to hopefully clarify my question. I think @ChrisRackauckas may have answered it for now but if there was a way to use the builtin function and not an outside lib that would be preferred. Thanks so much for the help so far!

Comment: Why built in an not a package? What's the difference in Julia?

Comment: Honestly I just thought it would be easier to distribute my code. Not a huge deal. I'm new to Julia so I hoping someone would be like "oh yeah you just left this out...".

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I ended up using your VectorizedRountines.jl package. Works great. Feel free to add that as the answer to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

We prefer to avoid these functions, since they allocate arrays that usually aren't necessary. The values in these arrays have such a regular structure that they don't need to be stored; they can just be computed during iteration. For example, one alternative approach is to write an array comprehension:

```
julia> [ 10i + j for i=1:5, j=1:5 ]
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  12  13  14  15
 21  22  23  24  25
 31  32  33  34  35
 41  42  43  44  45
 51  52  53  54  55
```

Or, you can write `for` loops, or iterate over a `product` iterator:

```
julia> collect(Iterators.product(1:2, 3:4))
2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 3)  (1, 4)
 (2, 3)  (2, 4)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to have an AbstractArray type that computes the values as necessary without allocations just like linspace though? Essentially an n-dimensional generalization of linspace.

Answer (score 4):

I do find sometimes it's convenient to use some function like `meshgrid` in numpy. It's easy to do it with list comprehension:

```
function meshgrid(x, y)
    X = [i for i in x, j in 1:length(y)]
    Y = [j for i in 1:length(x), j in y]
    return X, Y
end
```

e.g.

```
x = 1:4
y = 1:3
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
```

now

```
julia> X
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 2  2  2
 3  3  3
 4  4  4
julia> Y
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
 1  2  3
```

However, **I did not find this makes the code run faster than using iteration**. Here's what I mean:

After defining

```
x = 1:1000
y = x
X, Y = meshgrid(x, y)
```

I did benchmark on the following two functions

```
using Statistics

function fun1()
    return mean(sqrt.(X.*X + Y.*Y))
end

function fun2()
    sum = 0.0
    for i in 1:1000
        for j in 1:1000
            sum += sqrt(i*i + j*j)
        end
    end
    return sum / (1000*1000)
end
```

Here are the benchmark results:

```
julia> @btime fun1()
  8.310 ms (19 allocations: 30.52 MiB)
julia> @btime run2()
  1.671 ms (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

**The `meshgrid` method is both significantly slower and taking more memory.** Any Julia expert knows why? I understand Julia is a compiling language unlike Python so iterations won't be slower than vectorization, but I don't understand why vector(array) calculation is many times slower than iteration. (For bigger N this difference is even larger.)

**Edit:** After reading [this post](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4093#issuecomment-22827461), I have the following updated version of the 'meshgrid' method. The idea is to not create a meshgrid beforehand, but to do it in the calculation via Julia's powerful elementwise array operation:

```
x = collect(1:1000)
y = x'

function fun1v2()
    mean(sqrt.(x .* x .+ y .* y))
end
```

The trick here is the `.+` between a size-M column array and a size-N row array which returns a M-by-N array. It does the 'meshgrid' for you. This function is nearly 3 times faster then `fun1`, albeit not as fast as `fun2`.

```
julia> @btime fun1v2()
  3.189 ms (24 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
765.8435104896155
```

Comment: Two things. First, `fun1` should be `mean(sqrt.(X.*X .+ Y.*Y))` as this saves an array copy. That said, the bigger reason is simply that making arrays is more expensive than not making arrays. Also, in this case your arrays are non-`const` globals, which is often very slow.

Comment: After removing the 'return' and declaring `X` and `Y` as `const`, the computation time for `func1` is still 8.114 ms, only 0.2 ms faster. So, array computations are simply slow in Julia. My takeaway from this is to code Julia more like C and less like Python or MATLAB, i.e. use iterations instead of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Above, @ChrisRackauckas suggests that the "proper way" to do this is with a lazy operator but he hadn't gotten around to it.

There is now a registered packaged with lazy `ndgrid` in it:
https://github.com/JuliaArrays/LazyGrids.jl

It is more general than the version in
[VectorizedRoutines.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/VectorizedRoutines.jl)
because it can handle vectors with different types, e.g.,
`ndgrid(1:3, Float16[0:2], ["x", "y", "z"])`.

There are `Literate.jl` examples in the docs that show the lazy performance is pretty good.

Of course lazy `meshgrid` is just one step away:

`meshgrid(y,x) = (ndgrid_lazy(x,y)[[2,1]]...,)`